# How to download image gallery imbedded with javascript?

Tags: javascript, download, gallery

I'd like to know if there's a quick way to download all the images in an image gallery that's embedded with javascript on a site? I can click the arrow as part of the gallery to load the next picture but I want tp download the whole gallery :).

Answer (score 0):

Use a browser plugin/extension/app/whatever.

I used DownThemAll for Firefox for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.httrack.com/ to download complete website (HTML, javascript, css and images), with this you will not even have to even click on next